# WordPress how to set a CSS class dynamically to bbp_form_topic_type_dropdown

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way I can set a `CSS` class name to BBPress forum dropdown dynamically in my template file?

I have copied `BBPress`'s `form-topic.php` to my theme and now I am trying to customise styles of the elements.

Under `Create New Topic` area two dropdowns, i.e. **Topic Type** and **Topic Status** are being rendered using the following functions respectively - **`bbp_get_form_topic_type_dropdown()`** and **`bbp_get_form_topic_status_dropdown();`**, which are residing in  `wp-content/plugins/bbpress/includes/topics/template.php`.

In above functions I can add my class name where the following snippet is:

```
$r = bbp_parse_args( $args, array(
    'select_id'    => 'bbp_stick_topic',
    'default_css_class' => 'form-control',
    'tab'          => bbp_get_tab_index(),
    'topic_id'     => 0,
    'selected'     => false
), 'topic_type_select' );
```

but the problem is my change will be lost in case I need to upgrade BBPress!.

Two things I have already tried to avoid the above situation:

1. By copying `template.php` to my theme's folder and making changes to it: WP says the function is already defined, which is correct, so I had to discard that idea
2. By copying `template.php` and creating new function: Created new function like **`bbp_get_form_topic_type_dropdown_custom()`** and **`bbp_get_form_topic_status_dropdown_custom()`**, added my CSS class to them. But no dropdown was rendered at all!

I have started WP very recently so sorry if the question looks stupid. Any suggestion would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

After a few more searching I finally got the answer [here](https://bbpress.org/forums/topic/can-you-override-includestopictemplate-php-in-a-child-theme/). Thanks to [Robkk](https://bbpress.org/forums/profile/robkk/)!

I created a new function in my `functions.php` file, added my CSS class and then used `apply_filters` like this:

```
return apply_filters( 'bbp_get_form_topic_status_dropdown_tp', ob_get_clean(), $r );
```

In my `function.php` now I have this:

```
function bbp_form_topic_status_dropdown_custom( $args = '' ) {
        echo bbp_get_form_topic_status_dropdown_custom( $args );
}

function bbp_get_form_topic_status_dropdown_custom( $args = '' ) {
    // Parse arguments against default values
    $r = bbp_parse_args( $args, array(
        'select_id' => 'bbp_topic_status',
        'default_css_class' => 'form-control',
        'tab'       => bbp_get_tab_index(),
        'topic_id'  => 0,
        'selected'  => false
    ), 'topic_open_close_select' );
    ...
    ...
    <select class="<?php echo esc_attr( $r['default_css_class'] ) ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $r['select_id'] ) ?>" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $r['select_id'] ); ?>_select"<?php echo $tab; ?>>
        <?php foreach ( bbp_get_topic_statuses( $r['topic_id'] ) as $key => $label ) : ?>
            <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?>"<?php selected( $key, $r['selected'] ); ?>><?php echo esc_html( $label ); ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>

    return apply_filters( 'bbp_get_form_topic_status_dropdown_custom', ob_get_clean(), $r );
}
```